# Mishnayot not in Bavli

Tags: talmud-gemara, mishna, talmud-bavli

Does anyone know of a list of all Mishnayot to which there is no Gemara in Talmud Bavli? I.e., those Mishnayot that are not quoted at the head of a section of their own Gemara.

Apologies if this question has been asked in the past - I have looked and I could not find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Masechtos of Mishnayos not in Bavli:

- Pea, Demai, Kilayim, Sheviis, Terumos, Maasros, Maser sheini, Challa, Orla, Bikkurim. *From Seder Zeraim*.
- Shekalim. *From Seder Moed*.
- Eiduyos, and Avos. *From Seder Nezikin*.
- Middos, Kinnim. *From Seder Kodshim*.
- Keilim, Oholos Negaim, Parah, Taharos, Mikvaos, Machshirin, Zavim, Tevul yom, Yadayim, Uktzin. *From Seder Taharos*.

Comment: I think the question is if there are misnayot not mentioned in Gemara

Comment: @kouty i understand the questioner but your question simply is impossible to answer, some Mishnais are quoted at the begining of the Gemara and are not every single statement is explained by the Gemara. Also some Mishnais are only quoted inorder to ask questions but once again are not explained in the Gemara. Also how do you quote every part of the mishna not explained by the Gemara it would take you weeks...

Comment: Thanks. I have done that, although @kouty’s answer looks like exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Might also add that about half of Tamid (chapters 3 and 5-7) have no Gemara either.

Comment: @kouty He asked about Mishnayos not at the “head” of Gemaras, not ones that aren’t quotes. That said, that restriction alone means much of Eduyos actually *is* quoted in Bavli, by virtue of many of those Mishnayos being paralleled elsewhere.

Comment: @Meir Arguably none of it does. There’s plenty of room to argue that the “Gemara” on Tamid actually dates to the Geonim. (Compare the “Gemara” on Maseches Kallah.)