# Why is there no gemara for Mikvaot?

Tags: talmud-gemara, mikvah-ritual-bath

I've been told that Niddah is the only masechet in Taharot with Gemara because it has practical applications even when there is no temple.

But the halachot of Mikvaot are just as important nowadays as those of a Niddah. Why didn't the Amoraim make a Gemara for it?

Edit: I believe my question is not a duplicate. It acknowledges that there are reasons that most of Taharot don't have Gemara, but questions why specifically Mikvaot wasn't an exception like Niddah was.

Comment: Yadayim is also applicable to the laws of washing hands, whereas Zevachim which has a gemara is mostly about temple service. Being applicable today might be a reason but it isn't an exceptionless rule

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/100322/

Comment: @b_a Netilat Yadayim in our days is not actual halacha from the Torah (since we are Tamei nowadays anyway). It's just a Zikaron that was enacted by the Rabbis. The halachot of Mikvaot apply just as much today as in the past.  So I don't think the case for inclusion is as strong for Yadayim as for Mikvaot.

Comment: This has my reopen vote, for the reasons mentioned in the question (in the paragraph that begins "Edit". Note though that that info shouldn't be in the question, as it's meta-info, viz info _about_ the question).